# JQuery Finding Multiple Ids Via Chaining

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make my click event handler fire only if button 1 or button 2 get clicked.
I am not sure how to do an "OR" or RegEx here?

Below is a snippet of HTML and the click handler that I have so far:

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div id="statusbar">
   <button id='buttonId1>Button 1</button>
   <button id='buttonId2>Button 2</button>
   <button id='buttonId3>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#statusbar').find('button').attr("id",'buttonId1').click(function() {

    alert('clicked on invitations button');
});
```

Comment: `$('#buttonId1, #buttonId2').click(function() {})`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a comma to find elements using multiple selectors:

```
$('#buttonId1, #buttonId2').click(function() { });
```

Or you can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add multiple results together:

```
$('#buttonId1').add('#buttonId2').click(function() { });
```